# Ran `brew install ruby` even though I'm already using rbenv, can I just run uninstall?

Tags: ruby, homebrew, rbenv

I haven't updated my version of Ruby in forever and when reading the instructions for a new gem I figured homebrew's install would probably update me to the latest ruby version. As soon as I hit enter I remembered I'm using rbenv to manage my versions. If I run `brew uninstall ruby` will that just delete the version I installed with brew and leave my rbenv setup alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rbenv` and `brew` should be two different things. The location where `rbenv` installs its own `ruby` is completely different anyway.

Uninstalling your Homebrew installed Ruby shouldn't impact `rbenv` at all. It may mess up your path temporarily, so you may need to open a new shell window afterwards, though that depends on how Ruby was put into your path in the first place.

Comment: It's now telling me it refuses to uninstall ruby 2.5.1 because it's being used by vim. But I can run `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ruby`

Comment: Sounds like `vim` really wants to have Ruby around, but if you're going to force it and you're aware that `vim` might be upset, sounds like you've got a solution.

Comment: Well, yeah. I guess this is a different question. I'll google around and I guess start a different question if I can't find it.

Comment: You can set the `rbenv` version of Ruby to have higher priority in your `PATH` so any other Ruby installs are mostly irrelevant apart from the minor amount of disk space they take up. That way you don't have to worry about these other instances at all.

Comment: True, but I feel like that's setting me up for some obscure problem down the road, long after I've forgotten this ever happened

Comment: That's a valid concern, and `PATH` problems pop up all the time, but if you're using `rbenv` you're probably used to having the "wrong" Ruby show up to the party now and then. The `gem env` command can be useful when debugging Ruby problems as it tells you everything it knows about your current Ruby environment and mistakes should be fairly obvious there, especially the "shell path" part.

Comment: I took the chance that vim just wasn't checking down the path for rbenv installed Rubies and ran the uninstall. It all worked out, thanks.

Comment: Hope it's smooth sailing from here on out!